# How to get a value from controller.js file to html file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have stored a value in a scope on controller.js.How to get that scope value in html file.

**Controller.js**

```
myAppCont.controller('Listvalue',['$scope','$rootScope','$http',
function($scope,$rootScope,$http){

      city=$scope.val;
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-10" ng-controller="Listvalue">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-style" id="statusTable">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>values</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="align-center">
    <tr>
    <td>{{city}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the $scope variable inside the controller, Do it other way

```
myAppCont.controller('Listvalue',['$scope','$rootScope','$http',
function($scope,$rootScope,$http){
      $scope.city=val;
}]);
```

Then it will be evaluated and shown in the view

```
 <td>{{city}}</td>
```

Working [`Sample`](https://plnkr.co/edit/PbSageAJ27SdyV447sDg?p=preview)

Comment: @Divakar Check the sample

Answer (score 0):

Angular have 2 way data binding principle. The data you bind with the model is get reflected in the view.

The models in a respective controllers are accessed with $scope.

Whatever data you want to bind to the view should be through the $scope.

In this case, if you have, already stored data in `$scope.val`,

Bind that to your view,

```
<td>{{val}}</td>
```

This should work!